# ASP.NET MVC4 unobtrusive validation message incorrect for digit rule

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I am using jQuery unobtrusive validation in ASP.NET MVC4 to validate an input contains digits only:

**HTML**

```
<input class="form-control" 
       data-val="true" 
       data-val-digits="This field may only contain digits." 
       data-val-range="This field must be between 0 and 25." 
       data-val-range-max="25" 
       data-val-range-min="0" 
       data-val-required="This field is required." 
       id="DaysHoliday" 
       name="DaysHoliday" 
       type="number" 
       value="">
```

When I enter "3.5" in the input I correctly get the validation message "This field may only contain digits."

When I enter "foo" in the input I would expect to see the digits validation message, but I actually get the required validation message "This field is required."

Why is the wrong message displayed?

Comment: I don't know the validator in detail, but I assume that it sees things in the following manner: if the value cannot be parsed to _any_ number, it will treat it as missing; if it can be parsed but it's not the correct number type, it will tell you what's wrong with the number. Remember that value types are by default required in ASP.Net MVC (unless you play a bit in `Global.asax`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a demo that works fine for me in Safari, Firefox and Chrome, but NOT Explorer 10:  http://jsfiddle.net/e0uz8nrs/

Your issue appears to be browser-specific and being caused by the `type="number"` designation of the field.  It simply does not recognize text characters as anything, and therefore you get the same message as an empty field.

You could change the field to `type="text"` and it will behave more like you expect.  I don't believe there's any other workaround for this.

Comment: Yes, changing the input type to text has resolved this.